# NUI + iOS7 - no background color for buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nui

I'm experiencing some weird inconsistencies with [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui) under iOS7: some buttons doesn't appear to render with a background colour.

The app consists of a navigation controller. The buttons within the root view appears to be working just fine:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aFVqn9p.png]

A few segues later, there is an (at least to the Interface Builder) identical button, albeit with a different appearance all together:

[image]

I note that the navigation bar is inconsistent too in its rendering:

[image]

.... yet sometimes:

[image]

Do you guys have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess as I've never used NUI, but have you tried changing the button types to custom? When iOS 7 released I had issues with some buttons rendering oddly due to being set to a system type in the storyboard they were loaded from ...

Comment: can you paste some code here

Comment: @DavidDoyle Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @CharanGiri The benefit of NUI is the lack of code! I used the default stylesheet and only invokes `NUISettings init` in my `main`-function and `NUIAppearance init` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use `UIAppearance` instead. NUI is not compatible with iOS7 at this time.

Comment: http://classy.as/ does similar thing as NUI, uses css. Is saying that I think UIAppearance is better approach for the reason you've seen.